# Why can't I debug a simple Xamarin app that targets Android?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a simple Xamarin app on my Windows PC targeting Android and it is proving to be a real pain with problems at every single step of the way (no single step was without a lot of pain).  I am now at the step where I am trying to start the device as shown below:

[image]

When I try to start this device I see the following error:

[image]

I have been trying to sort this error for the last 1.5 days with no luck.  I have come across this webpage, which talks about the error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows#accel-issues-win

Therefore I run the following command:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel

I see this:

[image]

**Is this telling me that my CPU is not suitable for Xamarin development?** My research is telling me that this is just warning me that debugging could be slower.

I have also come across this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/.  I have installed it, but don't really understand what it is needed for because the Emulator appears to be installed as part of Visual Studio:[image]

Now see the image below:

[image]

Notice I have enabled Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform.

What is the problem? Please note that I have created a basic HelloWorld type app i.e. using the project defaults.

Comment: Have you verified that Hyper-V and other extensions are enabled in your EFI ("BIOS") setup screen?

Comment: @Dai, yes, I have verified that virtualisation is enabled in the bios - I already use docker without problems anyway.  I have also run a command, which supposedly enables Hyper-V.  Does this Emulator have to be installed independently of visual studio: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dai, do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: edit the VM in Manager and play with GPU settings

Comment: @w0051977 Have you tried a fresh install of Android Studio and tools to see if outside of Visual Studio/Xamarian that your PC is the issue? Also include the model number of your CPU (i.e. i7-XXXX some letter).

Comment: @Morrison Chang , the processor is: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         950  @ 3.07GHz, 3068 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s). Yes I have tried a reinstallation.

Comment: And you've tried disabling Hyper-V from Windows Features. See https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Known-Issues

Comment: disable Hyper-V and use [last HAXM version](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.5.1)